# Facebook asking for login again Android

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

this is my code which uses Parse to log a user in via Facebook.

```
public void onFacebookLoginClick(View v) {
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if ((currentUser != null) && ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(currentUser)) {
        Log.d("onFacebookLoginClick", "Already signed in");
        showHomeActivity();
    } else {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "", "Logging in...", true);

        List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");
        // NOTE: for extended permissions, like "user_about_me", your app must be reviewed by the Facebook team
        // (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/)

        ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if (user == null) {
                    Log.d("Facebook", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                } else if (user.isNew()) {
                    Log.d("onFacebookLoginClick: ", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                    showHomeActivity();
                } else {
                    Log.d("onFacebookLoginClick: ", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                    showHomeActivity();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is, the user logs in the first time (OK!), then the login dialog opens up again.

Note: When I close the dialog, it does take me to the next activity. But why can it be showing the login dialog twice?

Comment: So, if the user is not already linked to the Parse user the Facebook login dialog is shown twice and after both of them the user is redirected to your home activity?

Comment: No. User clicks on login with FB button, a login dialog is shown, user logs in, and that login dialog is still there! It never closed! So until user doesn't manually close the dialog, this action will repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue implementing this. I solved it by letting my code sleep for a few seconds before attempting to start the activity. It's possible this may be the bug.

--Why I arrived at this conclusion--

I found the loginCallBack in ParseFacebookUtils takes a few seconds to return with its result code/parse user.

No data was returned by the time I start the activity and the activity is configured to launch the login activity if no user is logged in. This made it appear as though the code wasn't logging in on first try. I believe the Parse Facebook logic is a little slower than the regular parse login logic.

The second time you run the code (click the button) the callback was already returned with the parse user and would successfully launch the activity without returning.